# Stripe IBAN Element Error 'The type `sepa_debit` is not a valid source type.'

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, onlinebanking, iban

I tried to implement the Stripe IBAN element, descriped right here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/iban

I used the exact same code, change the api key, but I keep getting this error
'The type `sepa_debit` is not a valid source type.'
But in the docs they write you have to use 'sepa_debit' as the type..

The Credit card example is working fine for me..

Comment: Have you turned sepa on in your account settings? - https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings

Comment: @AshleyMedway oh my fault, thank you. I didn't see that it's impossible to test sepa on test mode..

Comment: How I can IBAN of USA user?

Answer (score 7):

For try the [source type](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-source) "*sepa_debit*" on an [IBAN Element](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/iban) is indifferent if you are in live or test mode, the only requisite is enable the option "[SEPA Direct Debit](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sepa-debit)" under [Payment Settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings) section which is based in "invitation list" mode.

[image]

As they write:

> SEPA Direct Debit payments are available to Europe-based Stripe users
> in a closed preview. In order to activate SEPA Direct Debit, you will
> need to request an invite through your Stripe Dashboard.

And as [second condition](https://support.stripe.com/questions/accepting-sepa-direct-debit-payments-with-stripe):

> Before you can accept SEPA Direct Debit payments, your Stripe account
> needs to have regularly processed card payments for 30 days. SEPA
> Direct Debit payments are also subject to processing volume limits,
> and payments can fail if you exceed your limits. If you are a new
> customer or plan to process a high volume of transactions, please get
> in touch to request a review.

When you get accepted, you can try in live/test mode with your public and secret keys. Until you get accepted, you can use ONLY the public keys as demo which are showed in stripe docs as merchant demo, like for example this key (could be changed in future):

> // Note: this merchant has been set up for demo purposes.
>
> pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh